# Why is my Postman query on the OmniIndex API only showing partial data?

Tags: postman

I am trying to run a query through Postman on the OmniIndex API to retrieve data from my store.

But some of the blocks data  are only showing  The data store holds files and my full response is:

```
    {
    "results": [
    {
        "author": "Data has been redacted.",
        "context": "",
        "context2": "",
        "directory": "Data has been redacted.",
        "filecreateddate": "2023-05-19 13:54:47",
        "fileextension": "pdf",
        "filemodifieddate": "2023-05-19 14:03:34",
        "filename": "Data has been redacted.",
        "filesize": "1860991",
        "fullpath": "Data has been redacted.",
        "sentiment": "",
        "sentiment2": ""
    }
    ]
     }
```

As can be seen all of t he encrypted data points are replaced with "Data has been redacted".
My json request is (Without creds)

```
{

"analyticQuery": "SELECT authorowners, context, context2, sentiment, sentiment2, directoryowners, 
filecreateddate, filemodifieddate, fileextension, filenameowners, filesize, fullpathowners FROM WHERE

 hash='AFD0C8D2B777D056F2D23D4A4FB7D18BD238533317F6B3F9EF0589FB5784B8B3'",
 "password": "",
 "unitName": "",
"user": "",
"server": ""
 }
```

- I have looked around but cannot seem to find an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I work for OmniIndex and can help with your query.

The json request needs to have inside it a **key/value** pair of
'showProtected / true'

This will tell the API to show you the plaintext versions of ciphered data that you have access to.

I hope this helps! I got the answer from my OmniIndex expertise and the documentation.

https://omniindex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/omniindex/api.html#

Answer (score 2):

You are not receiving the data because the content is encrypted and by default it remains that way. If you wish to output the results you have to specify the point so your json request should read

```
{

"analyticQuery": "SELECT authorowners, context, context2, sentiment, sentiment2, directoryowners, 
filecreateddate, filemodifieddate, fileextension, filenameowners, filesize, fullpathowners FROM WHERE

 hash='AFD0C8D2B777D056F2D23D4A4FB7D18BD238533317F6B3F9EF0589FB5784B8B3'",
 "password": "",
 "unitName": "",
"user": "",
"showProtected" : "true",
"server": ""
 }
```

Note the showProtected key. It is defaulted to false

you can see the full request on Swagger Hub [Swagger Hub](https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/OmniIndexAPI/OmniIndex/1.0.0#/default/RunAnalyticQueryPost)